# Can't get Scrollmagic plugin to work as example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

Link to wanted behavior (slide on scroll): http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/section_slides_manual.html

I copied the source from the site but am having trouble reciprocating it's behavior.  I know there are some css that is moving from the source but it seems to be more of a javascript issue that I can't figure out.

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/zcgxxj44/

```js
 $(function () { // wait for document ready
  // init
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

  // define movement of panels
  var wipeAnimation = new TimelineMax()
   // animate to second panel
   .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {z: -150})  // move back in 3D space
   .to("#slideContainer", 1,   {x: "-25%"}) // move in to first panel
   .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {z: 0})    // move back to origin in 3D space
   // animate to third panel
   .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {z: -150, delay: 1})
   .to("#slideContainer", 1,   {x: "-50%"})
   .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {z: 0})
   // animate to forth panel
   .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {z: -150, delay: 1})
   .to("#slideContainer", 1,   {x: "-75%"})
   .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {z: 0});

  // create scene to pin and link animation
  new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: "#pinContainer",
    triggerHook: "onLeave",
    duration: "500%"
   })
   .setPin("#pinContainer")
   .setTween(wipeAnimation)
      .addIndicators({name: "1 (duration: 0)"}) // add indicators (requires plugin)
   .addTo(controller);
 });
```

```css
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
  body{
    position:relative;
  }
  #pinContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

   
 }
 #slideContainer {
  width: 400%; /* to contain 4 panels, each with 100% of window width */
  height: 500px;
            background:red;
 }
 .panel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%; /* relative to parent -> 25% of 400% = 100% of window width */
  float: left;
     background:blue;
 }
  .hola{
background:green;
height:120vw;
width:100vw;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/jquery.gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="hola"></div>
<div id="pinContainer">
 <div id="slideContainer">
  <section class="panel blue">
   <b>ONE</b>
  </section>
  <section class="panel turqoise">
   <b>TWO</b>
  </section>
  <section class="panel green">
   <b>THREE</b>
  </section>
  <section class="panel bordeaux">
   <b>FOUR</b>
  </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are missing some scripts here.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working example of the same.

```js
$(function() { // wait for document ready
  // init
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

  // define movement of panels
  var wipeAnimation = new TimelineMax()
    // animate to second panel
    .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {
      z: -150
    }) // move back in 3D space
    .to("#slideContainer", 1, {
      x: "-25%"
    }) // move in to first panel
    .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {
      z: 0
    }) // move back to origin in 3D space
    // animate to third panel
    .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {
      z: -150,
      delay: 1
    })
    .to("#slideContainer", 1, {
      x: "-50%"
    })
    .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {
      z: 0
    })
    // animate to forth panel
    .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {
      z: -150,
      delay: 1
    })
    .to("#slideContainer", 1, {
      x: "-75%"
    })
    .to("#slideContainer", 0.5, {
      z: 0
    });

  // create scene to pin and link animation
  new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: "#pinContainer",
      triggerHook: "onLeave",
      duration: "500%"
    })
    .setPin("#pinContainer")
    .setTween(wipeAnimation)
    .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

```html
<link href="http://scrollmagic.io/css/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://scrollmagic.io/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://scrollmagic.io/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/js/examples.js"></script>
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/js/lib/modernizr.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/js/lib/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/js/examples.js"></script>
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/js/lib/greensock/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js"></script>

<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="example-wrapper">
    <div class="scrollContent">

      <section class="demo" id="section-slides">
        <style type="text/css">
          #pinContainer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            -webkit-perspective: 1000;
            perspective: 1000;
          }
          
          #slideContainer {
            width: 400%;
            /* to contain 4 panels, each with 100% of window width */
            height: 100%;
          }
          
          .panel {
            height: 100%;
            width: 25%;
            /* relative to parent -> 25% of 400% = 100% of window width */
            float: left;
          }
        </style>
        <div id="pinContainer">
          <div id="slideContainer">
            <section class="panel blue">
              <b>ONE</b>
            </section>
            <section class="panel turqoise">
              <b>TWO</b>
            </section>
            <section class="panel green">
              <b>THREE</b>
            </section>
            <section class="panel bordeaux">
              <b>FOUR</b>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You just linked to every bit of javascript and css that scrollmagic uses for all of its examples not just the one that he is looking for.  This isn't a very good solution because he will just be loading a bunch of stuff he doesn't need